# Path().parent не срабатывает как ожидалось

Tags: python, pathlib

Нужно получить ближайшего родителя текущей рабочей директории.

```
In [1]: Path()
Out[1]: WindowsPath('.')

In [2]: Path().parent
Out[2]: WindowsPath('.')

In [3]: Path(Path().absolute()).parent
Out[3]: WindowsPath('D:/AnaPy')
```

Получить желаемое мне конечно удалось, но наверняка есть лучшее решение.
Я так и не понял, почему  `Path().parent`  не срабатывает.

Comment: Path() - это?...

Comment: и почему не срабатывает, когда в коде хорошо видно, что срабатывает. Просто это не совпадает с вашими ожиданиями, потому что вы ожидаете от parent немного не то, что оно делает.

Comment: Короче, потому что `Path().parent` работает со строкой (в которой может быть и не существующий путь), и про реальную иерархию директорий ничего не знает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В [официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#methods-and-properties) есть несколько предупреждений на этот счет:

> You cannot go past an anchor, or empty path:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> p = PurePosixPath('/')
> >>> p.parent
> PurePosixPath('/')
> >>> p = PurePosixPath('.')
> >>> p.parent
> PurePosixPath('.')
> ```
>
> **Note** This is a purely lexical operation, hence the following
> behaviour:
>
> ```
> >>>
> >>> p = PurePosixPath('foo/..')
> >>> p.parent
> PurePosixPath('foo')
> ```
>
> **If you want to walk an arbitrary filesystem path upwards, it is
> recommended to first call `Path.resolve()`** so as to resolve symlinks and
> eliminate `“..”` components.

Поэтому сначала воспользуйтесь `.resolve()`, как советуют в документации:

```
Path().resolve().parent
```

а еще лучше более явно указать текущий путь:

```
Path('.').resolve().parent
```